# 2D Sprite Scaling in Unreal Engine 4.13.2

Tags: sprite, collision, unreal-engine4, unreal-development-kit, unreal-blueprint

I'm working on a Sprite Scaling pickup for a 2D Platformer assignment, and have most of it worked out.

I am running into a few issues however.

When scaling the Capsule Component (It being the Parent object), when walking up to a sprite on the TileMap, the map disappears until you move away again.

I am not sure entirely why. The player is not falling off the map, and it will reappear again if you move to the side a little, but when the player is small and is colliding with the TileMap, it disappears.

Player Resize Code:

[image: Player Blueprint Code]

GIF of the described Issue:

https://gyazo.com/e23d24cfc9af406c2808bcf73ea5dad4

Any help is appreciated guys!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This question has been resolved.

Turns out that this is an engine issue with Unreal Engine using the TileMap. The TileMap is currently experimental and does not correctly handle rendering tiles when the Capsule Component is Scaled.

This bug has been reported to Epic Games and is awaiting a hotfix in the upcoming patches.